# Should "obake" be understood to refer to shapeshifters, or rather to things that have been transformed?

Tags: japanese

In the [tvtropes article on Youkai](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Youkai), the following remark is made on the meaning of "obake":

> *Obake* is another Japanese word that can indicate some type of  monster. Derived from the word for "to change", it generally covers the  subset of youkai that includes shapeshifting animals (hence the terms *bake-gitsune*, *bake-neko*, etc.) as well as [Animate Inanimate Objects](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimateInanimateObject) 〔i.e. *tsukumogami*〕. Confusingly, however, the word *obake* can also be used to refer to ghosts, also known as *yuurei*.

[The Wikipedia article on Yōkai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%8Dkai) contains the (unsourced) statement that

> *Yōkai* that shapeshift are known as *bakemono* (化け物) or [*obake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obake) (お化け).

The [Wikipedia article on Obake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obake) contains the (unsourced) statement that

> Literally, the terms mean *a thing that changes*, referring to a state of transformation or [shapeshifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapeshifting).

The implication that the *bakeru* root of obake/bakemono is related to the ability to shapeshift is a strong one at least as far as public opinion on the internet goes, despite the inconsistencies that can be noted with this etymology. In my estimation, the less incongruous root of the term would be that it refers to beings that *have undergone a change*; they might also (coincidentally) have shape-shifting powers. Many (perhaps not all) of the shape-shifting animals, which are considered *obake*, are transformations that happen when an animal has lived for a considerable amount of time (commonly 100 years); the *tsukumogami*, being items, commonly attain their status by considerable age as well, in particular by having been abandoned or forgotten or not well kept. In the case of *yurei*, the transition is that from the living to the dead. While this etymology seems to capture all of the cases that fall under *obake* (shapeshifting animals, animated items, ghosts), it would also exclude some other *yōkai* that are shapeshifters, but have not undergone a transformation, such as most prominently the *oni*, which ought to fall under *obake* if we considered it to refer to shapeshifting.

Is my reading of obake as referring to "transformed entity", rather than to "shapeshifter", a sensible one? Is there any support for it? Any credible scholarly sources that contravene it?